# copy/clone of keras subclassed models with custom attributes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a subclassed model with some custom attributes like this:

```
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, my_var, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.my_var = my_var

    def my_func(self):
        pass

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        config.update(
            {
                "my_var": self.my_var
            }
        )
        return config
```

Now I define model and clone it with `clone_model`

```
x_in = layers.Input(shape=(100, 100, 3))
x_out = layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(x_in)

model = MyModel(inputs=x_in, outputs=x_out, my_var="my_var")

cloned = tf.keras.models.clone_model(model)
print(cloned.my_var)
```

The model is copied ok, but without my_var

Is there any way to copy this type of model properly with all attributes (my_var and my_func)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

```
cloned = model.__class__.from_config(model.get_config())
```

as shown in the doc https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/clone_model#example

Comment: Thank you! Missed this in the docs.